# Tensorflow 2.5 on M1 Mac Mini is significantly slower then the previous Tensorflow-for-Mac version

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, mnist, apple-m1

I am trying to do some simple benchmarking on my M1 Mac Mini. I used to use the Tensorflow-for-mac version as described [on the Apple GitHub page](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos). Recently it stopped working, and I found that apple archived the mentioned repository. They now refer to [this page on their developer instructions](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/).
After following the instructions, I tried to run this super simple MNIST setup here:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 784)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               100480    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 101,770
Trainable params: 101,770
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

To my surprise, this simple model took around 10x longer to train, compared to the time it took with the previous TF version.
Each epoch takes around 10 seconds (previously it took 1s max).

I guess my question is, if this is a known bug or issue. Is there a way to fix this? The previous version won't work anymore on my machine.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at this one to confirm you have done it right. https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a great fix but you could try running this VM for the M1 https://www.parallels.com/ and then running it their. Dont know if it will improve your performance by much or at all but i used it to play a game that didnt run on a M1 mac but ran on an intel mac